# Running Ubuntu from flash drive crashes randomly with no apparent cause

Tags: suspend, usb-drive, crash

I have Ubuntu (and other Linux OSs) installed on a flash drive. It runs with no problems on various laptops, but I keep having issues with Dell laptops. It crashes randomly at any time. Sometimes it won't complete the boot process, other times it could run for a couple of hours before the problem occurs.

As far as I can determine, it seems that USB autosuspend may be kicking in, even though I have done everything to make sure that it is turned off.

I've been using the flash drive to boot and run successfully on a Toshiba laptop and a Lenovo laptop without any issues. I've even got Ubuntu to run on a Macbook Pro without issue. However, on two different Dell laptops, I get this problem. There's nothing special about them except that they are work laptops and are secured by Symantec Endpoint encryption. I don't think this is the issue, though, as the boot process goes to the flash drive before the Symantec software even starts.

I have tried a number of things that I have found by searching various forums:

1. Added usbcore.autosuspend=-1 to the end of my options in Grub
2. Made sure that the setting for autosuspend is set to 0
3. I've been through every option in the BIOS (EFI) adjusting any setting that looks like it might affect USB devices
4. In Windows, made sure that the OS cannot turn off power to USB devices
5. Looked through the journalctl logs, but cannot see anything obvious (although I'm not really sure what I would look for there) and I suspect that the crash happens before any useful information would be written to the logs

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions as to what might be the cause and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 20 Jul 2020

I've pasted one of my logs here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QqpvQwvw9y/

If I recall correctly, on this occasion it crashed just after the boot-up process and the login screen was about to be displayed.

Update: 26 Jul 2020

Yet another crash, but this time very early in the boot process. Once I was able to boot and login, there was not even any entries in the journal.

I suspect it must have something to do with the hardware, or maybe the UEFI, or the firmware?

Can anyone suggest what I should be looking for as possible causes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend posting the journal here as well.

Comment: I can't see how to attach a file, so is it just a question of copying and pasting the details? It's about 2000 lines.

Comment: You could use a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/).